# Calculating time intervals over history

Tags: sql, ssms

I have a table of bug activity history:

| BugID | OldStatus | NewStatus | DateModified |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | New | Assigned | 2022-06-01 |
| 12345 | Assigned | Waiting | 2022-06-02 |
| 12345 | Waiting | Assigned | 2022-06-04 |
| 12345 | Assigned | Waiting | 2022-06-05 |
| 12345 | Waiting | Assigned | 2022-06-06 |
| 12345 | Assigned | Confirmed | 2022-06-08 |
| 12345 | Confirmed | Coding | 2022-06-10 |
| 12345 | Coding | Testing | 2022-06-14 |
| 12345 | Testing | Closed | 2022-06-18 |
| 23456 | New | Assigned | 2022-06-10 |
| 23456 | Assigned | Waiting | 2022-06-10 |
| 23456 | Waiting | Assigned | 2022-06-15 |
| 23456 | Assigned | Waiting | 2022-06-15 |
| 23456 | Waiting | Assigned | 2022-06-16 |
| 23456 | Assigned | Waiting | 2022-06-17 |
| 23456 | Waiting | Assigned | 2022-06-19 |
| 23456 | Assigned | Confirmed | 2022-06-21 |
| 23456 | Confirmed | Coding | 2022-06-30 |
| 23456 | Coding | Testing | 2022-07-05 |
| 23456 | Testing | Closed | 2022-07-10 |

By BugID, I need the total days spent in Waiting (for more info from the bug reporter) and the total days from New to Closed.  **OR** The total days from New to Closed minus Waiting days.  The database has BugSubmitted which equals the New DateModified for each BugID.

I've calculated
DATADIFF(DAY, BugSubmitted, MAX(DateModified) over (partition by BugID)) AS 'Days to Close'.

How do I calculate just the Waiting days, i.e. 3 of 17 days for #12345 and 8 of 30 days for #23456?

Answer (score 0):

You may use the `LEAD()` function and simple aggregation as the following:

```
with cte as 
(
    select BugID,NewStatus,
    DATEDIFF(Day,DateModified, 
    LEAD(DateModified) Over (Partition By BugID Order By DateModified)) As Df 
    from BugHistory
)
select BugID, Sum(Df) As TotalDays, 
Sum(Case When NewStatus='Waiting' Then Df Else 0 End) as TotalWaiting
from cte 
Group By BugID
```

See a demo from ***[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017l&fiddle=0d1b97cbc72f26768c87ddbf66bb60fd)***.

Comment: I didn't know about cte (common table expressions) before.  This worked.  Thanks!